# Can't resume Windows installed alongside Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, hibernate

I have installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04.  Now I can't load windows.
It says: `delete restoration or resume.`

If I `resume`, it doesn't load and there is no message displayed.

If I delete restoration, then my windows will be gone and I'll have to reinstall everything.

How can I resume or at least load Windows?

Comment: First of all you need to rename it to dual boot rather than dually so people get it properly, second of all a screenshot would be very helpful.

Comment: the page doesn't load. there is two option that I have mentioned above. if I click continue, it just stay a black screen. if I delete, then it never comes up.